# Access Data with an Array of JSON

Tags: json

I have some json which looks like below (it is stored in a variable called message). I am trying to access the last json object value at this hierarchy -  set_attributes -> row. How can I do that thus far message[message.length].set_attributes.row has not worked. I am using node.js

```
[
    {
        "title":"Carib",
        "buttons":
        [
            {
                "type":"show_block",
                "title":"Add to Cart",
                "block_names":["[\"Add to Cart\"]"]
            },
            {
                "type":"show_block",
                "title":"More Info",
                "block_names":["[\"Add to Cart\"]"]
            }
        ],
        "subtitle":"10 | beer | 10000",
        "image_url":"url",
        "set_attributes":{"row":"23"}
    },
    {
        "title":"Stag",
        "buttons":
        [
            {
                "type":"show_block",
                "title":"Add to Cart",
                "block_names":["[\"Add to Cart\"]"]
            },
            {
                "type":"show_block",
                "title":"More Info",
                "block_names":["[\"Add to Cart\"]"]
            }
        ],
        "subtitle":"10 | beer | 10000",
        "image_url":"url",
        "set_attributes":{"row":"24"}
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy mistake to make, but I believe that you should actually be trying to access `message[message.length-1]` instead of `message[message.length]` - this is given that indexing starts at 0 and not 1, thus the greatest index will be one behind the number of elements... Your current code will be trying to access an element that doesn't exist because the pointer will be out of bounds (1 greater than the last element)

Try making this change :)

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: will try this but even when I do a log for `message[0]` it returns undefined.

Comment: have you tried just logging message on its own? and also typeof message to see if it's the type you're expecting